# how to connect with minicom to a cisco switch and a serial to rj-45 adapter to connect my computer in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet, serial-port, cisco

I just recently set up my CISCO switch. I'm trying to connect with minicom. I looked at several tutorials online of how to do this. I tried the tutorials on YouTube but the problem is they assume I have a serial port in my computer. I don't. I had to get a serial to RJ-45 adapter to connect my switch to my computer.

So when I tried the instructions the tutorial said like so:

adam@adam-Inspiron-5558:~$ sudo minicom -s
[sudo] password for adam:

```
    +-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | A -    Serial Device      : /dev/ttyUSB0                                  |
    | B - Lockfile Location     : /var/lock                                 |
    | C -   Callin Program      :                                           |
    | D -  Callout Program      :                                           |
    | E -    Bps/Par/Bits       : 9600 8N1                                  |
    | F - Hardware Flow Control : Yes                                       |
    | G - Software Flow Control : No                                        |
    |                                                                       |
    |    Change which setting?                                              |
    +-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
            | Screen and keyboard      |
            | Save setup as dfl        |
            | Save setup as..          |
            | Exit                     |
            | Exit from Minicom        |
            +--------------------------+
```

I also tried with a serial port:

```
ttyS0
```

Again, doesn't work with my RJ-45 connector. As proof that it doesn't work, here is what happens when I run:

```
sudo minicom
```

I get this either way after saving either setting as the default for minicom:

```
adam@adam-Inspiron-5558:~$ sudo minicom
[sudo] password for adam: 


Welcome to minicom 2.7

OPTIONS: I18n 
Compiled on Feb  7 2016, 13:37:27.
Port /dev/ttyS0, 12:00:02

Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys
```

I need to connect to my switch in order to practice my CISCO training. Could someone help me with this? I looked in the /dev/ folder of Ubuntu and didn't know which file is for the Ethernet port.

Could someone help me with this? Thanks.

Sincerely, yours truly, the world's ultimate n00b, Robert Mcilhenny

PS

I am connecting it to my computer with a serial to RJ-45 connector. The switch uses an RJ-45 to serial connector obviously, but so does my PC. So I know ttyUSB0 won't work and I know ttyS0 won't work. On top of that I have tried them both.

Please get back to me on this. Thanks.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CiscoConsole

Comment: adam@adam-Inspiron-5558:~$ dmesg | grep tty
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
adam@adam-Inspiron-5558:~$ dmesg | grep tty
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
adam@adam-Inspiron-5558:~$ 


I get that result whether or not the RJ-45 cable is connected. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use your LAN port on PC to connect console cable.

Because you don't have `COM` port on your PC you need some converter `USB to RS232`. Picture of converter is [here](https://www.google.rs/search?q=usb+to+rs232&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiet-PUtbrVAhWBtxoKHTB_DIwQ_AUICigB&biw=1536&bih=768). Then you will get `/dev/ttyUSB` port, when you connect converter, for communication with switch via `minicom`.

In converter connect cisco console cable. RJ45 connector of cisco [cable](https://www.google.rs/search?q=cisco+console+cable&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6mdzotrrVAhVDGsAKHQJQAr0Q_AUICigB&biw=1536&bih=768) connect to console port on switch.

Then your `minicom` with setting will work

> ```
> +-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | A -    Serial Device      : /dev/ttyUSB0                              |
> | B - Lockfile Location     : /var/lock                                 |
> | C -   Callin Program      :                                           |
> | D -  Callout Program      :                                           |
> | E -    Bps/Par/Bits       : 9600 8N1                                  |
> | F - Hardware Flow Control : Yes                                       |
> | G - Software Flow Control : No                                        |
> |                                                                       |
> |    Change which setting?                                              |
> +-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
>         | Screen and keyboard      |
>         | Save setup as dfl        |
>         | Save setup as..          |
>         | Exit                     |
>         | Exit from Minicom        |
>         +--------------------------+
> ```

Without `COM` port you can only use telnet/ssh, access via network, for access to switch but you switch must have configured ip address.