# Where do I find the correct serial/ethernet port in /dev to connect to my Cisco switch using screen?

Tags: networking, usb, cisco

[image: dmesg screenshot]

I'm trying to connect my Ubuntu to my Cisco business switch but I am having trouble finding the right serial port or ethernet port. Im using a usb to ethernet adapter on my laptop side. From there it's ethernet to Cisco console port.

The eth0(enx000ec6c688f9) in dmesg is what's connected directly to my laptop.

I'm trying to use screen to connect to my switch. But I can't find the right /dev/?file? to use. How do I find the right file?

Comment: Are you sure it is ethernet? Some switches are really serial, but happen to use an RJ-45 port like ethernet, but you need a serial cable like [this one](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/a2.datacaciques.com/17/06/23/3i73ir962f92l1v1/74951aade1d92e17.jpg). Consider trying one of those. Of course, you could also unplug that, do `ls /dev`, and then run that again once you plug the switch in. But I'd guess it isn't really ethernet which is why your adapter isn't working, and it just happens to use RJ-45

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to connect with minicom to a cisco switch and a serial to rj-45 adapter to connect my computer in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/942393/how-to-connect-with-minicom-to-a-cisco-switch-and-a-serial-to-rj-45-adapter-to-c). See also [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CiscoConsole) on the Ubuntu website

Comment: SOLVED, it’s all coming back to me. I connected to it years ago. It’s a Cisco SG-300-10 switch. It doesn’t have full Cisco IOS if I remember correctly. Therefore it doesn’t use the management console port on the back? if I remember correctly. I got it working using Ethernet port on the front years ago using the default switch ip. That’s the final answer. Thanks everyone. Perhaps that’s why I couldn’t find correct file in /dev using recursive ls and grep in /dev